# Desempilhando pilha dinâmica

Tags: c++, stack

Eu tenho um algoritmo de pilha dinâmica. Só que se eu inserir 10 elementos na pilha e for desempilhar sem remover o primeiro elemento ele da falha de segmentação. E se eu remover o primeiro elemento do topo sobrando 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 e depois desempilhar, ele remove 4 elementos ao invés de remover um só, entao ficando 9 4 3 2 1.

1. Como eu resolvo isso para que ele remova um só elemento ao desemplihar?
2. E como faço para inserir 10 elementos na pilha e desempilhar sem dar falha de segmentação?

O código:

```
#include <iostream>

struct pilha
{
 int num;
 pilha *prox;
};

int main()
{
 pilha *topo = NULL;
 pilha *aux;
 int op;
  do
   {
    std::cout << "\n\n\tPILHA DESEMPLILHA COMO ESTRUTURA DINAMICA"
                 "\n\tMENU DE ESCOLHA DA PILHA"
                 "\n\t1 - INSERIR NA PILHA"
                 "\n\t2 - CONSULTAR TODA PILHA"
                 "\n\t3 - REMOVER DA PILHA"
                 "\n\t4 - DESEMPILHAR A PILIHA"
                 "\n\t5 - ESVAZIAR A PILHA" 
                 "\n\t6 - SAIR"
                 "\n\tESCOLHA: ";
    std::cin >> op;

   if(op == 1)
    {
     std::cout << "\n\tINSIRA NUMERO NA PILHA: ";
     pilha *novo = new pilha();
     std::cin >> novo->num;
     novo->prox = topo;
     topo = novo;
     std::cout << "\n\tNUMERO "<<novo->num<<" INSERIDO COM SUCESSO!!!";
    }

   if(op == 2)
    {
     if(topo == NULL)std::cout << "\n\tPILHA VAZIA!!!";
     else
      {
       std::cout << "\n\tPILHA COMPLETA: ";
       aux = topo;
       while(aux != NULL)
       {
        std::cout << aux->num << " ";
        aux = aux->prox;
       }
      }
    }

   if(op == 3)
    {
     if(topo == NULL)std::cout << "\n\tPILHA VAZIA!!!";
     else
      {
       aux = topo;
       std::cout << "\n\tNUMERO: " << topo->num << " REMOVIDO COM SUCESSO!!!";
       topo = topo->prox;
       delete(aux);
      }
    }

   if(op == 4)
    {
     if(topo == NULL)std::cout << "\n\tPILHA VAZIA!!!";
     else
      {
       std::cout<<"\n\tTOPO: "<<topo->num;
       aux = topo->prox;

       while(aux != NULL)
       {
        aux = aux->prox;
        topo->prox--;
       }
      }
    }

   if(op == 5)
    {
     if(topo == NULL)std::cout << "\n\tPILHA VAZIA!!!";
     else
      {
       aux = topo;
       while(aux != NULL)
       {
        topo = topo->prox;
        delete(aux);
        aux = topo;
       }
       std::cout << "\n\tPILHA ESVAZIADA COM SUCESSO!!!!";
      }
    }

   if(op<1 || op>6)std::cout << "\n\tOPCAO INVALIDA!!!";
   else
   if(op == 6)std::cout<<"\n\tGOOD BYE ...!!\n\n";

   }while(op != 6);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo o problema está na forma como você está "desempilhando" a pilha:

```
aux = topo->prox;

 while(aux != NULL)
{
   aux = aux->prox;
   topo->prox--;
}
```

Aqui há dois pontos a se destacar.

1. Não parece fazer sentido remover todos os elementos sem libertar a memória.
2. Você não pode decrementar o ponteiro `prox` (ou fazer qualquer coisa do tipo), porque neste caso se trata de uma pilha dinânica. Decrementar e incrementar só funciona com vetores, porque no caso dos vetores, a disposição dos elementos na memória é contínua. No caso de pilhas dinânmicas (ou listas) não se sabe ao certo qual a posição do próximo elemento ou do elemento anterior.

Sugestão de código:

```
aux = NULL;
if(topo->prox){
   if(topo->prox->prox)
      aux = topo->prox->prox;
   std::cout << "Item " << top->prox << "destruido com sucesso.\n";
   delete topo->prox;
   topo->prox = aux;
} else std::cout << "Item não destruido.\n";
```

Comment: ainda nao deu certo eu fiz isso ele esvazia a pilha.

Comment: mas a intenção é fazer o quê?

Comment: levantar o topo remover o proximo manter o topo e todos os numeros após o proximo. entao se eu tiver  1 2 3 4 5 o topo é o 5 entao teria que levantar o 5 remover o 4 e quando eu digitar o 2 ele me mostraria 1 2 3 5

Comment: Vou fazer a edição

Comment: agora deu certo mas a minha duvida é qual parte ai eu utilizo para mostrar: std::cout<<"NUMERO: "<<4<<" REMOVIDO COM SUCESSO."; ?

Comment: conssegui fazer aqui : pilha *removido = new pilha(); removido = topo->prox; std::cout << "\n\tNUMERO: " << removido->num << " REMOVIDO COM SUCESSO!!!";

Comment: Está bem, mas não entendi o porquê de alocar novamente a memória (removido = new pilha()), se você acaba fazendo o ponteiro apontar para outro lugar. Eu não andei testando, e parece que há um erro no meu código, é std::cout << "Item " << top->prox->num

Comment: capricho meu na hora que escrevi aqui no codigo nao esta assim eu só criei o ponteiro mesmo...