# vetor de inserção da pilha retornando tudo zero

Tags: array, c++, stack

Galera esses dias postei o algoritmo deste endereço abaixo aqui pois tava com problemas ao desempilhar e remover foi resolvido até então. [Desempilhando pilha dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268979/desempilhando-pilha-din%c3%a2mica/268988?noredirect=1#comment551364_268988)

Mas como eu estava revisando o código e portanto deixando eles de maneira melhor resolvi colocar um `for` para que o usuário não fique digitando 1 no menu para inserir os números, então ele iria fazendo a inserção conforme o tamanho do vetor:

Entao eu fiz isso abaixo:

```
   if(op == 1)
    {
     for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
     {
      std::cout << "\n\tINSIRA NUMERO "<<i+1<<" NA PILHA: ";
       pilha *novo = new pilha();
       std::cin >> novo->num[i];
       novo->prox = topo;
       topo = novo;
      std::cout << "\n\tNUMERO "<<novo->num[i]<<" INSERIDO COM SUCESSO!!!";
     }
    }
```

Mas quando digito 2 ele retorna tudo zero. o que eu fiz de errado?

```
   if(op == 2)
    {
     i++; 
     if(topo == NULL)std::cout << "\n\tPILHA VAZIA!!!";
     else
      {
       std::cout << "\n\tPILHA COMPLETA: ";
       aux = topo;
       while(aux != NULL)
       {
        std::cout << aux->num[i] << " ";
        aux = aux->prox;
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Como foi definida a estrutura/classe `pilha` ?

Comment: é o mesmo algoritmo do link que coloquei aqui só mudei o valor int num; para int num[10];

Comment: eu mudei para num[10]; no meu aqui em base é o mesmo algoritmo ...

Comment: Se cada elemento da pilha tem agora um vetor com 10 números é necessário mostra-los a todos em cada iteração do seu `while`, começando do 0 até ao 9. Como tem apenas mostra um numero por elemento da pilha.

Comment: entao eu tentei fazer while(aux->num[i] <=10) mas da erros

Comment: Mas está a tentar inserir vários elementos na pilha seguidos com um `for` é isso ? Porque para fazer isso com o código que tem não necessita do vetor que acaba por complicar (apesar de também dar para fazer)

Comment: entao eu tentei fazer isso sem usar vetor, da forma como estava eu teria que acessar o menu caso quisesse inserir 10 elementos entao deveria escolher 1 e depois inserir, e ao fazer isso dava falha de segmentação sem definir num como vetor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se pretende adicionar vários elementos seguidos na pilha à custa de um `for` não necessita de transformar cada elemento da pilha num vetor, e pode manter a estrutura antiga que tinha:

```
struct pilha {
    int num; //sem ser vetor
    pilha *prox;
};
```

Alterando a inserção para:

```
for(i=0; i<=9; i++) {
    std::cout << "\n\tINSIRA NUMERO "<<i+1<<" NA PILHA: ";
    pilha *novo = new pilha();
    std::cin >> novo->num; //sem o ->num[i]
    novo->prox = topo;
    topo = novo;
    std::cout << "\n\tNUMERO "<<novo->num<<" INSERIDO COM SUCESSO!!!";//tambem sem num[i]
}
```

O próprio `for` já faz todas as inserções que pretende, consoante o número de vezes que o define para executar.

A leitura teria de ser ajustada para:

```
if(op == 2) {
    //sem i++;
    if(topo == NULL)std::cout << "\n\tPILHA VAZIA!!!";
    else {
        std::cout << "\n\tPILHA COMPLETA: ";
        aux = topo;
        while(aux != NULL) {
            std::cout << aux->num << " "; //sem ->num[i]
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
    }
}
```

---

O problema que tinha é que cada elemento da pilha tinha 10 números, mas você estava apenas a preencher o um deixando os outros `9` vazios. Analisando o `for` que tinha:

```
for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
 {
   ...
   pilha *novo = new pilha(); //criar um novo elemento para a pilha
   std::cin >> novo->num[i]; //preencher um numero apenas numa posição do vetor
   ...
 }
```

Repare como preenche apenas uma posição pois em cada iteração cria um novo `pilha`.

Comment: agora entendi, dei tambem uma mudada no algoritmo para nao ficar criando varias variaveis https://pastebin.com/UTLsSBqE